# What would be the Mage::getBaseDir(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) in Magento 2?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-2.1

in magento 1

```
$directory = Mage::getBaseDir(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).
```

how i set this in magento 2

Comment: BP."/pub/media";

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 protected $_directorylist;

public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList $_directorylist 
) {
    $this->_directorylist=$_directorylist
}
```

Now you can easily get media directory by simply writing this line of code

```
$this->_directorylist->getPath('media');
```

Comment: do not use hardcoded strings, use  constants `$filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::MEDIA);`

Comment: Glad to hear that it works for you @Rahulocodewire :)

Comment: @KeyurShah if i use like this $this->_directorylist->getPath('lib').... I'm getting Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException): Unknown directory type: 'lib'

Answer (score 0):

At **Magento2.X**, `Mage::getBaseDir()` a has been deprecated and introduce new class `Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList` for getting dir path.

So, on `__construct()`, need to inject the class  `\Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList`.then using `getUrlPath('media')` you can get media dir

```
public function __construct(
        ...
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList $dir,
        ...        
    ) {
        ...
        $this->_dir = $dir;
        ...
    }
  public function getMediaDir(){

    $this->_dir->getUrlPath('media')'

}
```

More details you can get from

http://blog.belvg.com/how-to-get-access-to-working-directories-in-magento-2-0.html
http://magento-quickies.alanstorm.com/post/66600254010/magento-2-base-directories

**Or, direct call of Object you can media dir**

```
$object_manager = Magento\Core\Model\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$dir = $object_manager->get('Magento\App\Dir');            
$base = $dir->getDir(Magento\App\Dir::MEDIA);
```

var_dump($base);

**NOte:** Direct call of Object manager is not good

Comment: are you sure? There are no classes "Magento\Core\Model\ObjectManager", "Magento\App\Dir"

Answer (score 0):

For Magento 2,
You can use like this, **Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA**

**Call storemanager to get storemanage Object and call your media directory using storemanager,**

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    }
```

In your function,

```
$dir = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
```

Comment: Thanks Rakesh for the answer but I think he is asking about directory not url :)

Comment: Please let me know if you have issue